# Why IPL 2020 arranged with zero audience but Dettol ODI series with audience?

Tags: indian-premier-league

Why do IPL 2020 arranged with zero audience but [Dettol ODI series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_cricket_team_in_Australia_in_2020%E2%80%9321) with audience?

Both happened during COVID19 pandemic going on.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a sports question; the two tournaments were played in different countries at different times, and the governments of the UAE and Australia set different rules. Some countries (notably New Zealand, and to a lesser extent Australia) have managed the pandemic much better than others, so the risk of allowing spectators is different in different places at different times.